# How to log with format, arguments, and thrown?

Tags: logging, slf4j

In [Logger](http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/Logger.html), I think I can't find any method for reporting with a formatted message and a throwable.

I found

```
error(String format, Object... arguments) 
error(String msg, Throwable t)
```

```java
try {
    doSomething(arg1, arg2);
} catch (final SomeException se) {
    logger.error("Failed to do something with {} and {}", arg1, arg2);
    logger.error("Failed to do something", se);
}
```

Is there any way to do like this?

```java
logger.error("Failed to do something with {} and {}", new Object[]{arg1, arg2}, se);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't be afraid, just do it! SLF4J is smart enough. If you provide more arguments than placeholders, the logger will attempt to cast the last argument to `Throwable`. If it succeeds, then you get a nice stack trace in the log. This feature was introduced in SLF4J version 1.6.0 -- see http://www.slf4j.org/news.html and also http://www.slf4j.org/faq.html#paramException.

Usage like the following works fine:

```
logger.error("one {} two {} error", new Object[] { 1, 2, new RuntimeException("stack trace") });
```

Starting with version 1.7.0 there are new varargs overloads, so you can simply use

```
logger.error("one {} two {} error", 1, 2, new RuntimeException("stack trace"));
```